# If my object is serializable, can I send an ArrayList<> of my object?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I am trying to send an `ArrayList<MyObject>()` over a `Socket` connection. `MyObject implements Serializable`, and I am using the `ObjectOutputStream` & `ObjectInputStream` at respective ends of the `Socket` with the corresponding methods on either end. On the one end I send:

```
output.writeObject(myList);
```

On the other end,

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myList = (ArrayList<MyObject>) input.readObject();
```

Now my question is if this is valid. I know that `MyObject` is serializable and there is no problem sending one of them over at a time. However, is this property preserved if I am sending multiple of these objects in some sort of Java collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing an array list is not a problem. Because it implements Serializeable. But you need to make sure MyObject doesn't contain reference to another class that doesn't implement serializable.

And object graph is maintained when you deserialize you will get everything back minus transient variables.

Comment: Helpful comment on how if MyObject contains a reference to another object that is not serializable there are problems, that may have been the issue I was seeing.

Comment: @mike If you had no problem sending one of them over at a time, you won't have had a problem sending them in an `ArrayList` either. What *was* the issue you were seeing?

Comment: I wasn't particularly sure what the source of the error was actually, the object I was getting on the receiving end was `null`. There were two protocols, however, when `ArrayList<MyObject>` might be sent over, and one of them worked fine, the other was sending over the `null`. It's obvious now my error was elsewhere, but I ended up using an alternative approach to fix the error

Comment: @mike If you received a `null` you sent a `null`. Non-transient non-serializable fields have nothing to do with that. They cause exceptions.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a similar error now, what if MyObject contains a JLabel (which is not by defauly Serializable). It's catching an ObjectNotSerializable exception, would that be the reason why?

Comment: @mike The class that isn't serializable is named in the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Object graphs are preserved in full generality, and `ArrayList` is `Serializable.`